# Node js, Call WebSocket server from http server

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

I have a node js ( supported by express js ) http application. So I had a `server.js` file as follows(not there complete code).

```
var app = require('./app/app');
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port, host);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
```

I later added websocket server to there. So it is like this now.

```
// app server
var app = require('./app/app');
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port, host);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
/**
 * websocker Server
 */
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var wsServer = http.createServer();
var url = require('url');
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({ server: wsServer });
var express = require('express');
var wsApp = express();
var port = 1337;

wsApp.use(function (req, res) {
    res.send({ msg: 'hello' });
});

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection from origin ');

    ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message);
        var json = JSON.stringify({ type:'message', data: {hello : 'hello'} });
        ws.send(json);
    });

    var json = JSON.stringify({ type:'message', data: {hello : 'hello'} });
    ws.send(json);
});

wsServer.on('request', wsApp);
wsServer.listen(port, function () { console.log('Ws server Listening on ' + wsServer.address().port); });
```

Now these two are working happily. What I want is on a `POST` call to the http server, I want to trigger the web socket server to broadcast something to all clients. My problem is How I can trigger websocket server from http server?
Routes of http server is defined in `app.js` file. from there how can I call websocker server function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you encapsulate your ws functionality in one single javascript file (e.g: websocket.js) you could export your websocket object as a module.

```
module.exports = wss;
```

and then require it in your http controller

```
var wss = require(websocket.js)
```

In this case it should be easy to use `wss.send({...})` wherever you like.

Answer (score 0):

This peace of code is working to me:

```
//websocket.js
'use strict';

var io = require('socket.io');
var callme;

function Websocket(server) {

    var server = io(server);

    server.on('connection', function(socket){
        console.log('Do something here');

    });

    callme = function (val) {
        //you my choose a specific cliente if you want, read the socket.io doc
        server.emit('I may emit it ' + val);
        console.log("Called " + val);
        return 'Somebody got it';
    }

}

Websocket.route = function(req, res, next) {
        if(typeof callme == 'function'){
            res.send(callme(req.param('t')));
        }else{
            res.send('Websocket server is not running');
        }

    };

module.exports = Websocket;
```

On the express app definition, I put

```
var Websocket = require('./websocket');
app.use('/blablabla', Websocket.route);
```

Then, on the server js file, which run the application, I put

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
var s = new Websocket(server);
```

This last line works like the tradicional io(server); would work.

After that, when you request the address /blablabla the route will execute your websocket method.

My solution is not in production yet, let me know if somebody got an error.