# Trigger WebSocket server from http server

Tags: django, websocket, uwsgi

I am using `Nginx` + `uWSGI` to deploy my `Django` app. Now I need use `WebSocket` to send message to all connected clients. So I use `Nginx` + `Daphne` to deploy `WebSocket` server which use `Django Channels`.

The problem is I do not know **how** to trigger the `WebSocket server` from `HTTP server` to broadcast something to all clients.

I searched the `stackoverflow` and just find one similar question [Node js, Call WebSocket server from http server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33893432/node-js-call-websocket-server-from-http-server). But the solution is specific to `NodeJS`.

So my question is:

- Should I call function of `WebSocket` server from `HTTP` Server?
- If so, How? And Whether has common method to implement the communication?
- If not, Should I just write all logic in `WebSocket` Server?

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For broadcasting you'll need to make groups. [See here](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_2.html#enable-a-channel-layer).

HTTP server is made up of synchronous code. So you'll need a code similar to this, which sends messages to group, but in a synchronous fashion by using `async_to_sync`:

```
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer

channel_layer = get_channel_layer()


def send_to_group_sync(group_name, data):
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(group_name, data)
```

which you can fire in your sync code (for example in your views) like this:

```
def index(request):
    send_to_group_sync('a_group', {
        'type': 'method_name',
        'message': 'to send',
        'another message': 2,
    })
    return render(request, 'some_folder/index.html')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, maybe you mis-understanding my problem, sorry for my poor description. I post my solution below, you can see it. Thanks.

Comment: @Fogmoon if you are able to find answer for your own question then that's great! You didn't mentioned client anywhere in your question which confused me to write this answer. I've edited it for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I find the [Python WebSocket client library](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client) can resolve my problem. I use it in my `HTTP server` to connect and communicate with the `WebSocket server`.

Although I do not know whether this method is common or reasonable, but it works. I will not mark this problem as resolved for a while to wait some more accurate suggestion.